# How to import JS file in main JS file in Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm still new in Threejs ...
I want to put some of my threejs code in another JS file and then use it in my main.js file
This is a simple similar code:

**main.js**

```js
import * as THREE from 'three'
import Box from './classes/Parts.js'
const box = new Box()
scene.add(box)
```

**Parts.js**

```js
class Box {
  constructor() {
    this.geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
    this.mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000
    });
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geom, this.mat);
  }
}
export default Box;
```

This is something similar to [this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-do-you-do-to-work-with-external-js-classes-files-and-put-this-on-a-main-js-file-with-modules/26564/2)

But I get this error: `THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add custom objects to the scene graph which are derived from `THREE.Object3D`. That is not the case for your `Box` class. Rewrite your code like so:

```js
class Box extends THREE.Mesh {
  constructor() {
    const geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
    const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000
    });
    super(geom,mat);
  }
}
export default Box;
```